Can a specific molecule have more than one point group assigned/associated with it?
I was working on a problem set that had me give the proper point groups for a set of given molecules. One of those molecules was benzene-1,3,5-triol. The answer I gave was that it was "approximately D3h, but actually C3h, C3v, or C1 depending on the actual orientation of the hydroxyl groups." The reason I gave this answer was because in the past, and in this problem set as well, my professor has given "conformation-specific" molecules to find the point groups of. For example, staggered ethane would have the "correct" assignment of D3d, but eclipsed ethane would have the "correct" assignment of D3h instead. This is something the textbook would similarly feature as well with analogous molecules like di(benzene)chromium. This led me to believe that the particular positioning of the atoms/bonds mattered in the assignment of point groups, which is why I gave all the possible answers plus a general approximation.
Needless to say, I was marked incorrect, and the correct answer was C3h. Part of his reasoning for marking me wrong was that each molecule could only be assigned to one point group. When I thought about that, it made a lot of sense. After all, the generation of a reducible representation for a molecule, reducing it to a combination of irreducible representations, and identifying the patterns of vibrational motion and whether they are IR or Raman-active is one of the applications of group theory and symmetry. (At least the only one I know.) This gives me the impression that, instead of point groups describing one "frame" of a randomly moving molecule (such as the rotation of ethane about its C-C bond), it considers the molecule itself and the entirety of its molecular motions. Otherwise every molecule would have the possibility of being in C1 if the atoms just happened to align weird at that one "frame," right?
With all that being said, I have to wonder. What is the correct way of thinking here? Is it that the specification of "eclipsed" vs "staggered" ethane is stupid and just an exercise in the textbook? If there is indeed only one point group for each molecule, which one is it for ethane? Is it the staggered one because that conformation is "more stable?" What justifies that a certain starting point or "origin" position of the molecule before it starts vibrating like crazy is the one the point group assignment should be based off of?
I've read through the chapters on point groups and symmetry in my inorganic and physical chemistry textbooks, but I can't seem to make sense of this problem on my own. I also can't find a good textbook in my library that talks about symmetry and point groups, especially at a level that I can understand. I would really appreciate it if anyone could provide me with help/appropriate resources on this matter.
P.S.
If it's worth mentioning, this is my first time at stack exchange and I am currently just an undergraduate student taking inorganic chemistry, so I do apologize if this question is too simple, inappropriate, or plain silly.
Edit: I failed to realize that the C3 point group is also possible as well

When a group has free rotation then it only makes sense to use an average geometry. Your molecule is D3h. The rotation time of the OH group will be picoseconds so it is only sensible to use an average geometry which in this case effectively means ignoring the H atoms. Sometimes is questions like this one you may be asked to find the point group for the structure as drawn in some particular configuration not the actual molecule.

Short answer: you were right they are wrong. A point group applies to a single conformer of a  molecule. A molecule may have many conformers, and as you observe they will typically have different point groups. So in fact it is a bad question, as insufficient data is provided. As for your other questions I will try to find time later today to answer, but as the answer already here says thermal averaging over conformers is relevant

kind of related: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-023-01541-0

Porphyrin, thank you for your comment. I agree that none of this would be a problem if the structure was explicitly drawn, but unfortunately it only says "benzene-1,3,5-triol."
I can understand the plausibility of what you said about taking the "average geometry," but I have some issues/clarifications regarding that. For example, could we not apply that same argument to ethane and say that since there is free rotation, it is only sensible to take the average, which means we would then have to treat ethane as if it were essentially linear and assign it to the D∞h point group?

Ian Bush, thank you for your comment. While it is nice to here that my initial thinking was correct, I still have some reservations. Once again, does this mean that the identity of a compound does not reveal its point group? That is to say "ethane" does not have a point group, but it merely has the potential to form conformers which belong to different point groups? I look forward to your insights regarding my other questions when you have the time.

Giuseppe Basile, thank you for your comment. This paper doesn't seem to exactly help with my problem, but it is an interesting read. Also, going through the references, I found a potential good resource in Cotton's "Chemical Applications of Group Theory" which I look forward to perusing for answers to my questions. Thank you.

Cotton's Book always assumes the conformation! (just like any other book, that i know of) It is a fairly good read thought, highly recommended.

Yes it would be logical to say its $D_{\infty h}$ but at high temperature only where any barrier to rotation is insignificant, at lower temperatures we can have conformers produced by interactions between the protons making barriers to rotation so we use our chemical intuition also.

It gets complicated when there are torsional degrees of freedom. For fast vibrations, the "origin" position is the lowest energy conformation. For molecules like butane, with a slow switch between two equivalent lowest energy conformations, you can't use this rule. Instead, you fix the torsion angle at some value, and then look at the fast vibrations (those that change bond lengths and angles).

Point groups are assigned to specific objects centered in Euclidean space. The shape can be anything, it might be the result of averaging over a number of different molecular conformations, or a single molecular conformation representing a snapshot in time. Molecular conformations are represented as definite structures described by a set of atom types with positions defined by rigidly fixed nuclear coordinates (electrons are usually ignored or can be taken to assume an average distribution according to the Born-Oppenheimer approximation). In the case of vibrational modes, the shapes refer to both the type and  position of nuclei and their direction of motion (momentum vectors) under small displacements in the harmonic well minimum.
While your answer was technically correct given your interpretation of the problem, your interpretation was evidently flawed. In other words, your teacher meant you to provide an answer based on an average ideal geometry, not one instantaneous geometry among an infinity in the ensemble of all possible position and momenta of all particles.
I'd say however if you argue enough your teacher might grant you additional credit, it sounds like an argument you can win.

Thank you for your answer. Wouldn't the "average" ideal geometry put it in the D3h group though? Or are you referring to the flat, all-planar -OH as the "ideal case?"
Additionally, correct me if I'm wrong, but is what you are saying then is that the "vibrational modes" refer to only "small-scale" deviations from the specific conformer, and thus for a specific molecule, a spectrum of it will incorporate the vibrational modes obtained from every "relatively stable" conformer it will adopt?

@Andrew I actually don't know what the minimum energy conformations are in this case, but the average is a literal average over all (energetically equivalent) conformations. Otherwise as the other answer suggest, the contribution to the average of different conformations is weighed by a Boltzmann probability term.

Each vibrational mode is a set of vectors, one of the vectors in the set originating at one of the nuclei. The absolute amplitude is irrelevant, only origin, direction and relative amplitude matter (a symmetry operation should preserve atom type and vector). Vectors are evaluated at the energy minimum of a single conformation.

I didn't understand your last question. Each vibrational mode corresponds to simultaneous displacement of all nuclei (albeit the displacement of a particular nucleus might potentially be described by the null vector). Different modes are orthogonal etc.

I suppose this might be something like the law of averages; or the Boltzmann distribution. An individual molecule may have one point group (or mass) but not all molecules in your sample will be the same. So as long as you explained that when writing your answers (and not afterwards) it might fly. Perhaps examples of each of the structures would have helped.
Having said that, there are potentially other point groups as well which are missed so going down the list of all potential groups is a rabbit hole. For instance, even with a flat benzene ring here, one conformer could be O—H pointing up at C1, down at C3 and parallel to the ring at C5, and so actually a chiral conformer

Hello, thank you for answering. I'm still confused, does this mean that a compound (such as ethane) itself does not have a point group, but the individual molecules in the bulk matter do? If so, how do I come to terms with the fact that a different point group would yield a different combination of irreducible representations, and thus give a different answer for the vibrational modes of "ethane?"
Additionally, could you clarify what you mean by "(or mass)"? I thought all molecules in the bulk matter individually had the same mass?

Wouldn't the sample conformer you gave also belong to the C1 point group? That said, you did help me realize that I did miss some point groups. For example, if the O-H bonds where pointing 45 degrees out of the benzene plane it would belong to the C3 point group, right?

Sorry, the "or mass" was an incomplete thought, but no, consider isotopes   And yes, I believe you are right for  the O-H bonds pointing 45 degrees out of plane.

Oh yes, I forgot to consider isotopes. Sorry. That said, I think the description of having differing point groups for individual molecules in bulk matter at a moment in time is still more complicated. For one, at least the individual molecules that possess differing isotopes retain those masses throughout its existence. What about benzene-1,3,5-triol? If I say, this one molecule is in the form of a conformer that belongs to the C3h group, how do I reconcile the fact that the vibrational modes it would give are only "correct" so long as the molecules doesn't actually move?
